# SyntaxError: invalid syntax for COLLECTSTATIC (PYTHON)

Tags: python, django, deployment

I am following a tutorial on youtube for deploying a django app on DigitalOcean.

I type in: `python3 manage.py collectstatic`

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mochimoko/django_project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mochimoko/django_project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/mochimoko/django_project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mochimoko/django_project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/mochimoko/django_project/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 661, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 767, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 727, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mochimoko/django_project/users/models.py", line 11
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

I know the code is right cause I got in straight from GitHub.
I am a complete beginner at this. I know that indentation could be the issue here but everything looks fine to me.

Here is the code for the manage.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kawrgs):
        super().save(*args, **kawrgs)

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Comment: do you install Pillow?

Comment: In your Onetoonefield use related_name='user'. Then try to collectstatic

Comment: change it to `self.user.username`, (you may get error warning) it will work correctly,

Comment: @BidhanMajhi Try to prevent all warnings if you can. Warnings exist for a reason: They may lead up to unexpected behaviour in the future.

Comment: All I was referring about IDE error due to dynamic language. I said that just because username is in User model not in Profile model so it can show no 'username' member. Not referring to any programming error, though. @JerkMan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `f-string` in Python 3.5 but they appeared in Python 3.6.

Change `f'{self.user.username} Profile'` to be `'{} Profile'.format(self.user.username)` or change your Python to be 3.6.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. This was my first post. I almost gave up but good thing this site and people like you exist to help. As someone who is trying to change their life and get out of a dead end job, I would like to thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please make vote up and mark my answer as solution if it helped according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok. Done! Thanks!